# Can't get graphical .ttf font to work in Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop on the Mac

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, fonts, mac, ttf

I'm trying to use the Keyrune 'font', basically just .ttf of all magic sets. It's built as web font, but is .ttf and is being 'seen' by both PS and AI, as the typeface shows up in the autocomplete dropdown. However, when I try and select them, it fails to select. The Keyrune type does NOT show up in the drop down picklist, which is also strange. (Clearly, something isn't working, but just not sure what.)

[image: Keyrune showing in Illustrator(even the visual preview!]

[image: Keyrune showing in Photoshop]

Comment: The typeface does show up in FontBook and scales perfectly well in the preview panel...

Comment: Here's the typeface I'm talking about: https://andrewgioia.github.io/Keyrune/

Comment: It works for me in Illy CS6, using Glyphs to insert these keyless characters. Note that I have "Enable Missing Glyph Protection" switched off by default, because I like to be in full control of what I enter and in what font. Similar in Photoshop CS6 – although it doesn't have a Glyphs palette (!); I didn't try but I imagine copy/paste will work.

Answer (score 1):

Graphic fonts (icons, logos, etc.) are often assigned to obscure characters that don't correspond to your keyboard. For Keyrune, you can copy/paste the correct characters into illustrator using the [reference sheet](http://andrewgioia.github.io/Keyrune/cheatsheet.html).

If you are working with less documented fonts, use [TruFont](https://trufont.github.io/) to view the assigned unicode. 
 It is possible to remap keys using TruFont by copy/pasting icons into a new  TruFont font file.